# Checking to see if values of both defaultdict match for same keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, defaultdict

I have two `defaultdicts` and essentially I want to see if the values on both dictionaries match up for the same corresponding keys. For example: `{1,4}` `{1,4}`. So it looks for matching keys which is `1` and then checks to see if their value match up `4` which it does.

So in my case I have:

```
keyOne = [30, 30, 60, 70, 90]
valueOne = [3, 4, 6, 7, 0]

KeyTwo = [30, 30, 60, 70, 90]
valueTwo = [4, 5, 6, -10, 9]
```

I create two `defaultdicts` as such:

```
one = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in zip(keyOne, valueOne):
   one[k].append(v)

two = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in zip(keyTwo, valueTwo):
   two[k].append(v)
```

I then want to add the entries where the keys match but the values don't - so I write this, but it doesn't work:

```
three = defaultdict(list)

for k,v in one.items():
  for key in k:
    if key in two.items():
      if (value != v):
        three[k].append(value)
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong and it would mean a lot if someone could help me fix it. I'm new to programming and really want to learn

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? What error do you get?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just do `one == two`?

Comment: And what about using `Counter` instead of `defaultdict`?

Comment: `k` is a single key, which makes `key` an element in a *key*; neither `k` nor `key` is likely to be a tuple like ones coming from `two.items()`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice `Counter`... counts. It doesn't aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

You got a typo and can simplify your loop:

> ```
> from collections import defaultdict
>
> keyOne = [30, 30, 60, 70, 90]
> valueOne = [3, 4, 6, 7, 0]
>
> keyTwo = [30, 30, 60, 70, 90]   # typo KeyTwo
> valueTwo = [4, 5, 6, -10, 9] 
>
> one = defaultdict(list)
> for k, v in zip(keyOne, valueOne):
>    one[k].append(v)
>
> two = defaultdict(list)
> for k, v in zip(keyTwo, valueTwo):
>    two[k].append(v)
> ```

```
three = defaultdict(list)

for k1,v1 in one.items():   # there is no need for a double loop if you just want
    v2 = two.get(k1)        # to check the keys that are duplicate - simply query
    if v2:                  # the dict 'two' for this key and see if it has value
        three[k1] = [value for value in v2 if value not in v1]

    # delete key again if empty list (or create a temp list and only add if non empty)
    if not three[k1]:
        del three[k1]

print(three)
```

Output:

```
# all values in `two` for "keys" in `one` that are not values of `one[key]`
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {30: [5], 70: [-10], 90: [9]})
```

Using `dict.get(key)` returns `None` if the key is not in the dictionary and eliminates the `if` - checking before retrieval. You still need the `if` afterwards though - but I think this code is "cleaner".

See [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict[key]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey)